# Validating special form of IP address

Tags: php, regex, ip

I have encountered a strange IP which has redundant zero values among the octets. Is there anyway to properly validate this as an IP or use regular expression to remove those redundant zeroes?

example is of follows:
218.**064**.215.239 (take note of the extra zero at the second octet "064").

I do have one working IP validation function but it will not validiate this Ip properly due to the nature of the regular expression unable to accept that extra zero. Following is the code in PHP:

```
function valid_ip($ip) {
    return preg_match("/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])" .
            "(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/", $ip);
}
```

thanks for any help in advance peeps! :D

Comment: Out of curiosity, why exactly would you want to validate an IP address? This isn't typically input by the user.

Comment: erm, i am filtering a result extracted from a website. in this results are dates etc etc. im trying to extract only the ip :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will correct them:

```
$ip = "123.456.007.89";
$octets = explode(".", $ip);
$corrected = array();
foreach ($octets as $octet) {
 array_push($corrected, (int)$octet);
}
echo implode(".", $corrected);
```

Comment: hmm this doesnt work. something wrong with the implode statement.

Comment: Yup, I'm typing up a corrected version as we speak. One moment.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept the zero like this:

```
^(0?[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])(\.(0?[0-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$
```

Play with this regular expression on [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/h6BGQpKhjy).

The `0?` I added matches zero or one occurence of `0`. So `0?[1-9][0-9]` for example matches both `010` and `10` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a go yourself? It's really quite simple.

`|1[0-9][0-9]|` matches 100-199, as you are now wanting to match 000-199 (as above that it is 200-155) you just need to make a set for the `1` to be `1` or `0`.

```
function valid_ip($ip) {
  return preg_match("/^([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])".
          "(\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/", $ip);
}
```

And that can be refactored down (allowing leading zeroes) to:

```
function valid_ip($ip) {
  return preg_match("/^([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])".
          "(\.([01]?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])){3}$/", $ip);
}
```

Or to strip these unneeded zeros:

```
function strip_ip($ip) {
  return preg_replace( '/0+([^0])(\.|$)/' , '$1$2' , $ip );
}
```

Comment: would be best if i could change the current IP to a normal one without the zeroes. thanks though! :)

Comment: @phpnoob: See amended answer. (The clearer you are in your questions, the clearer we can be in our answers.)

Comment: hmm thanks and sorry for the trouble. but your second valid_ip has a No ending delimiter '^' found error. any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: @phpnoob: That was a typo on my part. Updated answer - try again.

Answer (score 0):

Change the bare `|1` occurrences to `|[01]`. Are you sure this is not supposed to be interpreted as an octal number, though? Some resolvers do that.

Comment: i'm trying to compare IP address and another IP of mine does not have this extra redundant zeros hence i have to do some sort of filter :(

Answer (score 0):

Use [ip2long()](http://php.net/ip2long).

Comment: there is a difference betwen ip2long for IP with zeros inside them and without.

Comment: ip2long appears to return the correct value with or without the leading zeros.

Comment: hmm i tested with the question given. i took out the redundant zero and there was a different number shown as a result of the ip2long :(

Comment: interesting.  Perhaps it depends on the PHP version.

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out where those extra zeroes are coming from. Those leading zeroes can't be just dropped. On most platforms they mean that the octet is in octal form instead of decimal. That is: `064` octal equals `52` decimal.